# How would I prove that if 11n-5 is odd, then n is an even number using only a direct proof?

Tags: logic, proof-writing, alternative-proof, parity

I've been able to prove this statement through contraposition and contradiction but I'm struggling to prove it through a direct proof. It seems I always get it in the form where 11n=2(k+3).

Comment: I'm not sure what difficulty you perceive.  You seem to show that if $11n-5$ is odd, then $11n$ is even.  Now $2$ is a prime number, and $2$ does not divide $11$, therefore $2$ must divide... what?

Comment: Try using modulus properties, if Remainder(a,b) is c then Remainder(a+k,b) is c+k

Answer (score 0):

Since the right-hand side has $2$ as a factor, and $2$ and $11$ are coprime, the left-hand side also has $2$ as a factor. This relies on the [fundamental theorem of arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic), where every positive integer can be represented as a unique product of prime numbers.

Comment: 11 is a prime number itself, so how would I be able to factor a 2 out of it?

Comment: $2$ must be a factor of $n$. If $2$ is not a factor of $n$, then the LHS would be not divisible by $2$, whereas the RHS would be divisible by $2$ - contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume $11n-5$ is odd then there exists integer $k$ such that

> $11n-5=2k+1 \implies 11n=2k+1+5 = 2k+6 = 2(k+3)$.

Now as $k$ is an integer we get $k+3$ is an integer. We can set $m = k+3$ then we get $11n = 2m$ and $2m$ is an even number which implies $11n$ is an even number. As we have found $11n$ to be an even number this implies that $n$ must be even since the product of two odd numbers will be odd.

Comment: Thank you for the reasoning. Do you know how I would go about writing that as a formal proof e.g. getting it to the form where n=2k and then conduct an existential generalization on that statement?

Comment: That is a proof, thus we can conclude there exists an integer $j$ such that $n=2j$ since by definition a number is even if it can be written in the form $2j$ for some integer $j$.

Answer (score 0):

$11n - 5 \equiv 1\ (\textrm{mod}\ 2)$

$11n \equiv 0\ (\textrm{mod}\ 2)$

Since $11 \equiv 1\ (\textrm{mod}\ 2)$,

$11n \equiv 1 * n \equiv n \equiv 0\ (\textrm{mod}\ 2)$.